# How do I know when cycle is over in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I do have this piece of code to determine how many instructions are executed.

```
  movl 10, %eax
  movl 0, %ecx
ciclo:
  addl %eax, %ecx
  decl %eax
  jnz ciclo
```

In other examples, I found it easier because there was a `cmpl` at the end of the cycle. But as this case, how do I know how many instructions were executed?

Comment: Have no idea of assembly but always thought that one instruction in asm equals one cycle.

Comment: @Nanoc Modern processors can do up to 4 instructions per cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this world changes so fast...

Comment: And of course one instruction can always take multiple cycles, and that's nothing new :)

Comment: @Nanoc, looks like by "cycle", OP meant loop iteration, not CPU clocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional jumps only check the state of flags, they don't care how they got set. `CMP` sets flags, but a bunch of other instructions do too. This is all written in the instruction set reference. `DEC` sets the zero flag that `JNZ` checks if the result is zero (no surprise there). As such the loop runs 10 times because `JNZ` repeats while the flag is **not** set.

You can also run this in a debugger and see for yourself :)

Comment: I get that result too, but the result is supposedly number of instructions = 32 and I don't see how

Comment: The loop runs 10 times, so that's 10*3 instructions, plus the first two makes it 32.

Comment: That's it. Thank you Jester!